# Javascript script element set inner text

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, code-injection

We need to add a javascript element inside an iframe (its inside the same web/domain so no security problems attached). We got it working but dont know how to fill the script content betwen its tags...how would you do it?

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeX');
var iframedocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;

var script = iframedocument.createElement('script');

script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.innerText = 'alert(\'hello\')'; //this doesnt work
script.value= 'alert(\'hello\')'; //this doesnt work either

var head = iframedocument.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

head.appendChild(script);
```

Desired result in the iframe document:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert('hello');
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/FU7ZK/

Comment: it does seem to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/mRgn7/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try:

```
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.innerHTML = 'alert(\'hello\')';
```

Comment: I tested it : OP version doesn't work on FF but it works with innerHTML.

Comment: I mean the guy who asked the question... What's the abbreviation on SO  (*Stack Overflow*)?

Comment: SO is StackOverflow, and what's the full form of OP? I have seen in many places! Got it... **Original Poster**! :)

Comment: @dystroy `innerText` is not an attribute in Firefox!

Comment: Yes, that's why I said you're right (and upvoted you) : innerText isn't standard and isn't implemented in FF (*Firefox*). Sorry for the bad abbreviations (not even an acronym for Firefox).

Comment: My bad, i tried innerText and seeing it didnt work i didnt try innerHTML

Answer (score 4):

I had problem with script.innerHTML as it doesn't work in IE8-.

```
script.text = 'alert(\'hello\')';
```

script.text works better for me.
Found on: [Create script tag in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201485/create-script-tag-in-ie8)