# Create script tag in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I was testing our site, in IE8 and got the dreaded `Unexpected call to method or property access.` error.

After lots of debugging (IE8's devtools suck), I found the offending line.

```
$('<script>').html(JSData).appendTo('head')
```

The problem is `$('<script>').html(JSData)`.  I tried running just that in the console, and I still got the error.

Why can't IE8 set the `.html` on a newly created script tag?

P.S. This fails too:

```
$(document.createElement('script')).html(JSData)
```

**UPDATE**: I tried to create the script tag without jQuery:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptTag.innerHTML = JSData;
```

On the `scriptTag.innerHTML = JSData;` line, IE8 gives `Unknown runtime error`.  Thanks IE8.

Comment: Have you tried using `text` instead of `html`?

Comment: Seems like it'd be easier/better to just `eval()` the script anyway.

Comment: @Pointy: I could use `eval` (or rather, jQuery's `$.globalEval`), but I figured this may be "faster".

Comment: Did you try `$('<SCRIPT DEFER>')` to avoid the [security issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897%28VS.85%29.aspx) in IE ?

Comment: @adeneo: `$('<script defer>').html(JSData)` still throws `Unexpected call to method or property access.` :-(

Comment: Did you try the recommended methods in the MSDN article ?

Comment: @adeneo: Is that *seriously* what Microsoft recommends? =/

Comment: @adeneo: Haha, their example doesn't even work! http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/insertScript_2.htm  EDIT: It works in IE8, not Chrome.  I kinda need my solution to be cross-browser.

Comment: @Shmiddty: `$('<script>').text(JSData)` still gives the error :-(

Comment: Am trying to add a script of type text/html. defer isnt working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your javascript only method needs to add the script element to the document.

IE<9 does not recognize innerHTML or childNodes on script tags, but all browsers support the text property.

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.text= JSData;
document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work.  Curious that `$('<script>').text(JSData)` doesn't.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: jQuery's .text() sets the textContent or innerText properties (not the text property).