# "Unknown runtime error" in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am making add Script utility function for my project.it is working good in chrome,firefox,IE10,IE9 but it is throwing **"Unknown run time error" in IE8**

```
util.addScript = function appendStyle(scriptcontetnt) {
    var st = document.createElement('script');
    st.type = "text/javascript";


    st.innerHTML = scriptcontetnt; //throw error at this point

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);
    return true;
};
```

I know using innerhtml throw errror in ie8 so i  read diferent threads  related to this but did't get any correct solution for this issue

Comment: How are you calling it? and on what line does it break?

Comment: Why do you need inject JavaScript code? This is a security concern in my opinion

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproductible example, some sort of HTML file with all the code needed to trigger the problem, including the value for the `scriptcontetnt` parameter?

Comment: at st.innerHTML = scriptcontetnt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHTML may not be the best solution for a script tag, try this:

```
util.addScript = function appendStyle(scriptcontetnt) {
    var st = document.createElement('script');
    st.type = "text/javascript";

    try {
      st.innerHTML = scriptcontetnt;     
    } catch(e) {
      // IE has funky script nodes
      st.text = scriptcontetnt;
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Create script tag in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201485/create-script-tag-in-ie8) you should use `text` instead of innerHTML in IE < 9

```
function appendStyle(scriptcontetnt) {
   var st = document.createElement('script');
   st.type = "text/javascript";
   st.text = scriptcontetnt; //throw error at this point
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);
   return true;
};
```